# How to substitute part of expression with function variable (Goal: create function that solves expression numerically for one of the variables)

Tags: functions, replacement

I have a complicated expression that contains N variables.

I want to create a function of N-1 that solves for one of those variables

Toy example:

```
expr = a^2-Sin[a*b]
astar[b_] := NSolve[expr==0, a, Reals]
astar[1]
```

does not work. I hoped it was equivalent to

```
NSolve[(expr/.{b->1})==0,a, Reals]
```

which does work.

I also tried

```
expr = a^2-Sin[a*b]
astar[b_] := NSolve[(expr/.{b->b})==0, a, Reals]
astar[1]
```

but that also doesn't work.

Comment: `astar[v_] := NSolve[(expr /. b -> v) == 0, a, Reals]` works - your `b->b` didn't work because that will become `1->1` due to evaluation order.

Comment: @flinty Okay, duh. I tried that final paragraph while writing the question but I guess I didn't do that seriously enough and had already decided I need help. Sorry about that. But still, is that the canonical way to do what I want to do?

Comment: No idea. It does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Functions should have explicit parameters.

```
expr[a_, b_] = a^2 - Sin[a*b];
```

Functions that use numeric techniques should restrict their parameters to numeric values.

```
astar[b_?NumericQ] := NSolve[expr[a, b] == 0, a, Reals];

astar[1]

(* {{a -> 0.}, {a -> 0.876726}} *)
```

Alternatively, get the exact solution

```
astar2[b_] := Solve[expr[a, b] == 0, a, Reals];
```

The exact solution is expressed as a [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expression

```
(* {{a -> 0}, 
   {a -> Root[{-Sin[#1] + #1^2 & , 
     0.8767262153950624459721623939201240\
      4608`20.315993684930827}]}} *)
```

Its approximate numeric value is the same as provided by `astar`

```
% // N

(* {{a -> 0.}, {a -> 0.876726}} *)
```

Comment: I don't type the epxression myself, it's the result of something like `sol = p[x]/.DSolve[a*p''[x] + b*p[x]+c+d*Sin[e*x], p, x] `. Is it really cleanest to convert this into `expr[xx_, aa_, bb_, cc_, dd_, ee_] = sol /. {a->aa, b->bb, c->cc, d->dd}` first?

Comment: Thanks for the good practices by the way. You recognized correctly that I have no idea what I'm doing

Comment: By not specifying initial conditions you have two additional parameters. Making replacements is not necessary; using `Set`, the RHS will be evaluated immediately. `expr[x_, a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, p0_, pp0_] = 
DSolveValue[{a*p''[x] + b*p[x] + c + d*Sin[e*x] == 0, p[0] == p0, p'[0] == pp0}, p, x] // Simplify`

Comment: @Bananach, I just wanted to add some emphasis to BobHanlon's answer to make sure the point wasn't lost. The typing is tangential to the main point. The replacement strategy is just winding yourself around an axle. The main point here is that MMA uses an expression-rewriting model of computation. This, expr[a_, b_] := a^2 - Sin[a*b], tells you how expr[x,y] will be rewritten regardless of what x & y are. In particular, they can be symbols. And this, astar2[b_] := Solve[expr[a, b] == 0, a, Reals], shows that this style allows you to leverage composition.